# How to change icons on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to change icon when user select item on list.I manage to change the icon when click on the item, but the issue if user click on other item I want to change prev item to init state, like play music and pause.

my template:

```
  <div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="item in items"
           class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right" ng-init="item.playing = false">
            <img ng-src="{{ item.user.avatar_url }}">
            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <h4>{{ item.artist }}</h4>
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="selectItemToPlay(item);item.playing = !item.playing">
                <i class="{{item.playing == true && 'ion-pause' || 'ion-play'}}"></i>
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: call your own `init` method on click of other buttons? How many buttons are there?

Comment: On item have 1 button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the selected item (say its itemId or $index) in one more variable. Say selectedItemId. This should be common for ng-repeat and not set initialized for each ng-repeat.

Set this variable on click of the item.

```
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="selectItemToPlay(item);item.playing = !item.playing;selectedItemId=item.Id">
```

And set other items to init state if the selected item id is different from clicked one.

```
<i ng-class="{'ion-pause' : item.playing, 
            'ion-play' : !item.playing || selectedItemId !== item.id}"> </i>
```

//Together

```
<div class="list">
    <a ng-repeat="item in items"
       class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right" ng-init="item.playing = false">
        <img ng-src="{{ item.user.avatar_url }}">
        <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
        <h4>{{ item.artist }}</h4>
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="selectItemToPlay(item);item.playing = !item.playing;selectedItemId=item.Id">
            <i ng-class="{'ion-pause' : item.playing, 
            'ion-play' : !item.playing || selectedItemId !== item.id}"> </i>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code was just an idea. selectedItemId variable was not set in parent scope in my sample above and hence the icon did not change. Initializing the variable works and changes the icon but not the state of the previous button. You would have to explicitly change the state of previous button. Pls check http://plnkr.co/edit/7ANndIuHCFaGyjWkw7sa?p=preview (if you have id for items) else http://plnkr.co/edit/n3TGM9WIjzSxw6jgLnx8?p=preview (based on ng-repeat index)

Comment: OK I got the idea, I wanted to resolve this without using the controller method...thnx!

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought (without controller) but the state was not toggling although i was able to toggle the icon. So you end clicking twice on the previous item to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <i ng-class="{'ion-pause' : item.playing,
               'ion-play' : !item.playing}">
 </i>
```

Or

```
 <i ng-class="{item.playing ? 'ion-pause' : 'ion-play'}">
 </i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive, which conditionally sets CSS classes based on an expression. For your code:

```html
 <i ng-class="{'ion-pause': item.playing, 'ion-play': !item.playing}"></i>
```